# How to remove unwanted letters in strings split by character

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of nba teams and I want to remove all the unwanted first letter or special characters in front.

```
Teams              |  W  |   L  |   Pct

*-Houston Rockets  | 65  |  17  |  0.793 

y -Golden State    | 58  |  24  |  0.707

x -Boston Celtics  | 55  |  27  |  0.671

x -Philadelphias   | 52  |  30  |  0.634

e -Denver Nuggets  | 46  |  36  |  0.561
```

### To become this:

```
Teams           |  W   |   L  | Pct

Houston Rockets |  65  |  17  |  0.793 

Golden State    | 58   |  24  |  0.707

Boston Celtics  | 55   |  27  |  0.671

Philadelphias   | 52   |  30  |  0.634

Denver Nuggets  | 46   |  36  |  0.561
```

Comment: I assume you are talking about Pandas DataFrames? Also, please show what you have tried, and format your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['*-Houston Rockets', 'y -Golden State',
               'x -Boston Celtics', 'x -Philadelphias',
               'e -Denver Nuggets'])

res = s.str.rsplit('-', 1).str[-1]

print(res)

# 0    Houston Rockets
# 1       Golden State
# 2     Boston Celtics
# 3      Philadelphias
# 4     Denver Nuggets
# dtype: object
```